# Jordan Normal Form- Where is my mistake?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A:=\begin{pmatrix} -4 & 12 & 6  \\ -5 & 12 & 5\\ 4 & -8 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $$\mathbb{X_A}=(2-\lambda)(2-\lambda)(2-\lambda)$$

The eigenvector $v_1$ for the Eigenvalue $ \lambda =2$ is $v_1= \left( \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}\right)$ for $\ker(A-2E)^2 = E^3$.

So to construct the Jordan Normal Form I have chosen $$v= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix},\qquad\text{and}\qquad u= (A-2E)*v = \begin{pmatrix} -6\\-5\\4 \end{pmatrix} $$ so $$ T = \begin{pmatrix} -6 & 1 &0 \\ -5 &0 & 1 \\4 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore $$ T^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0& \frac{1}{4} \\1 & 0 & \frac{3}{2} \\0 & 1 & \frac{5}{4} \end{pmatrix}$$

So for the Jordan Normal Form I calculated:

$$J=T^{-1} A T = \begin{pmatrix}  2&1&-2\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

I hope you can help me finding my mistake, I'm not very familiar with the theory to Jordan-Forms yet. Thank you in advance

Comment: ...contruate?${}$

Comment: Seems to be a typo in $A$.  Its characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda-2)(\lambda^2-4\lambda+12)$.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of your matrix is $(2-x)(12-4x+x^2)$.

Comment: Ah, the $(2,3)$ entry of $A$ should be $5$, not $6$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael you are right!!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your calculations are correct for the *actual* matrix $A$...

You have done well to choose an element $v \in \ker(A - 2E)^2 \setminus \ker(A - 2E)$ as your second column.  From there you chose $(A - 2E)v$ as your first column.  So, the first two columns of your $T$ are correct.

For the final column, you must select another element of $\ker(A - 2E)$, linearly independent to that first column $u = (-6,-5,4)$.  So, for instance, we can take 
$$
T = \pmatrix{-6&1&1\\-5&0&0\\4&0&1}
$$
Or if you prefer
$$
T = \pmatrix{-6&1&2\\-5&0&1\\4&0&0}
$$